# implementing a circular queue in python - a level standard

Tags: python, error-handling, queue, circular-buffer, index-error

i am trying to implement a circular queue in python and my current program keeps giving me error, and I would like to know the problem and solve it.

my current program is :

```
# circular queue

class circularQueue:
   def __init__(self, maxsize):
        self.front = 0
        self.rear = -1
        self.queue = []
        self.size = 0 # elements in the queue
        self.maxsize = maxsize #size of the array(queue)

   def isEmpty(self):
       if self.size == 0:
            return True
       else:
           return False

   def isFull(self):
       if self.size == self.maxsize:
          return True
       else:
          return False

   def enQueue(self, newItem):
       if self.size == self.maxsize:
           print('Queue Full')
       else:
           self.rear = (self.rear + 1) % self.maxsize # mod = remainder
           self.queue[self.rear] = newItem
           self.size += self.size

   def deQueue(self):
       if self.size == 0:
           print('Queue Empty')
           item = null
       else:
           item = self.queue[self.front]
           self.front = (self.front + 1) % self.maxsize
           self.size = self.size - 1

       return item
```

and if i try to operate

```
q = circularQueue(6)
q.enQueue('k')
```

it says

```
self.queue[self.rear] = newItem
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Please help me ......

Comment: Well, what is the length of `self.queue` at this point, and what is the value of `self.rear`?  A simple `print` command or two should highlight the problem.

Comment: I'm confused by this code. Parts of it are for an unbounded queue (like starting with an empty list, and multiplicative growing); others are for a fixed-length circular queue.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to fill in a list element that doesn't exist.  Instead, when you're extending the existing list, you have to use `append`:

```
self.queue.append(newItem)
```

Also, I don't think that you want to *double* self.size each time you do this -- look at that next line:

```
self.size += self.size
```

Try

```
self.size += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You start off with `queue=[]`, `size=0`, `rear=-1`, and `maxsize=6`. So, what happens in `enQueue` the first time you call it?

```
if self.size == self.maxsize:
```

Nope, `0 != 6`.

```
self.rear = (self.rear + 1) % self.maxsize # mod = remainder
```

OK, so `self.rear = 0`

```
self.queue[self.rear] = newItem
```

Now you're trying to assign to `self.queue[0]`. But you created an empty queue; you can't assign to the first element of it.

The simplest fix here is to start off with `self.queue = [None for _ in range(maxsize)]`. Then the queue always has `maxsize` elements.

Or, if `None` could be a reasonable value to store in the queue, it'll probably be easier to debug if you create a special `_sentinel = object()` in your initializer and store that `_sentinel` in the empty slots. (You seem to have some special `null` value in your code that you return on `deQueue` when empty. If that's not an error, it may be even more helpful to have a `_sentinel` that's neither `null` nor anything that can be inserted—basically, if your unit tests ever get `_sentinel` back, you know you counted the circle wrong somewhere.)

You can get fancier and grow until `maxsize` and only then start going around the circle, but you only need that optimization if you're going to be creating lots of queues with large maxsizes but most of them never get near the maxsize. So just keep it simple.

Finally:

```
self.size += self.size
```

What? Doubling the `maxsize` might make sense for an unbounded queue, but this is a bounded queue. And doubling the in-use `size` never makes sense. You probably just wanted `+= 1` here.

Comment: thank you so much ! it's really helpful and easy to understand.